# Contentplaceholders in masterpage resizes

Tags: asp.net, contentplaceholder

being new to asp I seem to be stumbling into a problem. 
I have a masterpage with a table and several buttons. So far , so good. 
When i go to a different file that uses my masterpage my contentholder changes it's size and that's not the way I wanted it ( for instance if I put in a label or some text). How do I prevent this from doing this?

For clarification I have got a screenshot. 
The first screenshot is how I want it (look at the distance between home, trailer etc. and the title "DOCHTERS").

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/firstgu.png/

The second is what happens is I put in a label or another object (or even plain text ) of some sort(look at the distance between "DOCHTERS" and home, trailer etc.).

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/secondg.png/

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix this? 
Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run this application and see if turns out right because sometimes its just something with the WYSIWYG engine of the IDE.

Comment: thnx for your respons. I did run it and it appears the same in the browser.